# GRUNT installs without package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install --save-dev grunt grunt-contrib-concat grunt-contrib-uglify grunt-sass grunt-contrib-less grunt-contrib-watch
```

But no package.json is ever created in the folder where I ran those commands.

When I run grunt from command line:

```
>> Error: Unable to read "package.json" file (Error code: ENOENT).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: run `npm init` if you want to create a `package.json` file

Comment: Thanks. if you create an answer vs. a comment I can credit you for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I run grunt from command line:
>
> ```
> >> Error: Unable to read "package.json" file (Error code: ENOENT).
> ```

None of the commands you ran would have created a `package.json` file, so unless you manually created a file named "package.json" including an empty JSON object (`{}`), it makes sense that the commands would fail to save the dependencies in the `package.json` file.

If you run `npm init` from command line, it'll create a `package.json` file with basic settings.